# JCarousel only runs in IE11 when I have the inspect element window open

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, jcarousel

This is driving me absolutely insane..So I'm trying to add JCarousel to a website I'm working on, and all was going well until it came time for the dreaded IE compatibility test.

For whatever reason, the carousel will only work if I have the inspect element tab open. I can't figure it out for the life of me.

I thought it might have something to do with the fact that I was loading it into a div that was set to display:none and then making it visible, but I turned all that off I still run into the same problem.

Here's a link to the site:

http://www.consultgray.com/newdesign/co/#team

If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but our client still uses this and we just experienced this issue.

@user3696000 your solution works well.

> Problem solved! Apparently JCarousel decides whether it is a horizontal or a vertical carousel by auto detecting the width if it isn't explicitly specified.. while this wasn't a problem in any of the other browsers, IE was returning a large vertical value than horizontal. I just added ({ vertical: false }) to my jcarousel instantiator and it solved the problem. – user3696000

Comment: Thank you! Rescued my day ;)

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely you have console.log() statements in your code.

Comment: I just checked and console.log() isn't anywhere in my code nor is it in jcarousel or jquery. I do not have enough space to post code in the comments unfortunately and my reputation isn't high enough to answer my question yet.

I can see that it is still *sorta* doing something without the inspect element tab open.. the pagination is working still and when it gets to the last slide it shifts up 10 pixels.. definitely not what it is supposed to do though

Comment: Problem solved! Apparently JCarousel decides whether it is a horizontal or a vertical carousel by auto detecting the width if it isn't explicitly specified.. while this wasn't a problem in any of the other browsers, IE was returning a large vertical value than horizontal. I just added ({ vertical: false }) to my jcarousel instantiator and it solved the problem.